# How to set class name to child element of a wrapper element?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

```
<custom-img
  class="decrease-item"
  img-src="images/minus-green.svg"
  @click="event => callDecreaseItem(event, itemId)"
/>
```

Above is the block where an image component is being called

```
<template>
 <picture>
   <source type="image/svg" :srcset="imgSrc" />
   <source type="image/webp" :srcset="imgSrc" />
   <source type="image/avif" :srcset="imgSrc" />
   <img :src="imgSrc" :alt="imgAlt" />
 </picture>
</template>
```

Above is the `<custom-img/>` component.

By default the class name given to the `<custom-img/>` component is added to the `picture` tag.

Is there any way to add the class name to the image tag of the `<custom-img/>` component as the component renders?

Comment: So you want to render <img :src="imgSrc" alt....> with the class decrease-item?

Comment: Yes. <img  class="decrease-item" :src="imgSrc" :alt="imgAlt" />

Comment: Is there a reason why you just don't put it on the ```<img>``` tag right away?

Comment: The class name has to be passed down as prop and the style has to be inside the child component instead of the parent component.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to [disable attribute inheritance](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance), using `inheritAttrs: false` on your `custom-img` component,
and use `v-bind="$attrs"` on your child `<img>` element.

```
<template>
 <picture>
   <source type="image/svg" :srcset="imgSrc" />
   <source type="image/webp" :srcset="imgSrc" />
   <source type="image/avif" :srcset="imgSrc" />
   <img v-bind="$attrs" :src="imgSrc" :alt="imgAlt" />
 </picture>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  // ...
}
</script>
```

That way the class attribute, as well as any non prop attribute, will be placed on your child `<img>` element.